# Json Accelerator and AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

When the operation is running, I can not enter data in JSON model CREATED BY ACCELERATOR.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"you are in a tableViewController");
self.title = @"NavigationOrdini";


NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stampa6x3.com/json.php?azione=ordini"]];
AFJSONRequestOperation* operation;

operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:req
                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{

    [[ordiniModel alloc] initWithDictionary:JSON];



}
             failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, NSError
                       *error, id JSON) {
                 [self setTitle:@"Dictionary"];
                 NSLog(@"failed! %d",[error code]);
             }];
[operation start];


ordiniModel*test;

NSLog(@"il valore è %@",test.ordini.description);

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What do you get as a response?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: the response is all right! nothing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFJSONRequestOperation is asynchronous, meaning it that the code continues to execute while the rest of the app runs.  The completion block are run when the code actually completes.

So try:

```
NSLog(@"you are in a tableViewController");
self.title = @"NavigationOrdini";
ordiniModel *test;  // <-- create variable here

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stampa6x3.com/json.php?azione=ordini"]];
AFJSONRequestOperation* operation;

operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:req
                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{

    test = [[ordiniModel alloc] initWithDictionary:JSON]; // <-- Assign here
    NSLog(@"il valore è %@",test.ordini.description);


}
             failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, NSError
                       *error, id JSON) {
                 [self setTitle:@"Dictionary"];
                 NSLog(@"failed! %d",[error code]);
             }];
[operation start];
```

Comment: [test initWithDictionary:JSON]; //<- the error is: Expression result unused

and when log this:
NSLog(@"this is the risultate: %@",[test description]); //<- when recall this method, value is: this is the risultate: (null)